# How to pass data and events between named views in Vue Router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have layout like this:

```
.------------------------+----------------.
|  Current Tab Title     |      Controls  |
+------------------------+----------------+
|  Tab1 Tab2 [Tab3]                       |
+-----------------------------------------+
|  Main Content                           |
|                                         |
'-----------------------------------------'
```

The "Controls" field contents should logically belong to the current tab. But I cannot put it in the same Vue component because it should be rendered in the different place of application template.
Also, tab title should depend on the current tab chosen.

I made `Tab1` etc a `<router-link>` components.
For `Current Tab Title` I abused the [`$route.name` field](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html).
I can use [named views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views) to display `Controls`.

But I cannot understand how to have some controls in `Controls` block which would depend on and influence the state in current tab.

For example, for `Tab1` we want to display a checkbox which will influence some behavior of the tab. So its state should be stored in `Tab1` component, not in `Tab1Controls` component. But how could I connect them, i.e. pass current value of the `checkbox` from `Tab1` *instance* to `Tab1Controls` instance, and pass an event back from `Tab1Controls` instance to `Tab1` instance?

This could obviously be solved with `Vuex` but I would like to avoid it.

General recommendation is to move state up the hierarchy, but I don't think it is possible with router. And anyway, it will make things a mess, because `checkbox` data should belong to either `Tab1` or `Tab1Controls`, and has nothing to do with other tabs.

Comment: You're talking about application level state management which is exactly what Vuex is for. Why not use it? The alternative is an event-bus but that's really just a hack

Comment: Why isnt it possible with router? <router-view @emittedEvent="handle" /> is valid

Comment: @Estradiaz because `<router-view>` is a wrapper that loads components within. It does not bind any event listeners to those components

Comment: @Phil i thought passing `data.attrs` would do this? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/ca68c6b71cafc2056f666b19f55f79303c0bb5fa/src/components/view.js#L109

Comment: @Estradiaz in that case, you might be right. I feel like I tried it ages ago and it didn't work but perhaps now it does

Comment: I just tried, and looks like `<router-view @event="handler()">` really works.
But still it is very inconvenient, so for now I will stick to `BaseTemplate` approach. Thanks @Estradiaz.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach I came to. It is far from ideal but at least it works and allows me to keep state where it should belong.

First, I created a `BaseTemplate` component which contains most of the markup of the app. I.e. the `App` component holds just a bare minimum, and most of the body (including immutable parts) is moved to `BaseTemplate`:

```
// BaseTemplate.vue
<template>
<div>
  <header>
    <slot name="title">{{ title }}</slot>
    <slot name="controls"/>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <router-link ...>
    <router-link ...>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <slot/>
  </main>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title'],
};
</script>
```

```
// Tab1.vue
<template>
  <BaseTemplate title="First Tab">
    <template #controls>
      ...
    </template>

    main content goes here...
  </BaseTemplate>
</template>
...
```

This way, all props related to Tab1 belong to Tab1 component, and at the same time common markup is moved to the separate component.

Now to the downsides.
Unlike the "normal" setup where common controls/navigations are outside the route-view, in this setup they are in fact different component instances for each tab. So they blink when switching.
Not sure if it can be mitigated somehow.

Comment: this actually is nice - and now put named views into those slots^^ -> `<router-view name="controls" />` and use them like `{path: "/any", components: { default: A, controls: B, title: C}}`

Comment: But then we get back to the original problem - because it is hard to share state between these different components.
My scheme with `BaseTemplate` allows me to have common state between "main content" and "controls" template.